# prevent double form submission on refresh

Tags: php, forms, post, redirect, php-5.3

I have a simple question. I know that I can prevent a form to re-submit itself when the user reloads the page by using the Post/Redirect/Get Pattern. But my question is, will this pattern work if I'm redirecting the user back to the same page where the form was submitted? I mean, I don't want to redirect the user to another page.

Any help please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, but you have to remember to redirect him without the GET params.

so you can

```
header('Location: same_page.php?status=done');
die();
```

this way you are removing the param, and you need to support the `status=done` to show a message or what ever you want.

Comment: Without the *POST* params of the forms